# How to make margin top of the mydatepicker?

Tags: css, datepicker

I am using mydatepicker from https://www.npmjs.com/package/mydatepickeras follows in my application.The issue is it is sticking upto the top corner of the browser ,I want to add margin top to it.

I want to edit its css ,specifically the margin-top of the datepicker,
Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
.mydp { margin-top: 40px !important; }
```

To your css file.

Comment: this is working as expected but gave rise to one more issue..just beside this i have a dropdown,after setting this css,there is a kind of diagonal distanc between the two.They arent coming on one straight line.can you help on this pls?

Comment: Can you please send screenshot or better, demo?

Comment: Dude, I can't help you with literally no information. There could be million things wrong with your code. If you don't send demo, or add your code in JSFiddle, i can't help you